# Jersey REST channel on weblogic returned 'null' instead of serialized JSON - no error

Tags: java, json, weblogic, jersey, jackson

I have jersey REST channel deployed on weblogic. All methods are configured to return JSON data. Jersey is using jackson inside. One of this method is working all the time and is returning the correct data, but the other returns 'null'. Literally, this means, 'null' is written on the screen. But the method definitely does not returns null, because I log everything.

There seems to be no error, since no error is printed in logs, and I set 'INFO' level for root logger in log4j configuration. So I'm a bit lost - no idea what can be wrong when no error is reported and simply null is returned. Anyone can help? How to at least find out what is wrong?

**--edit--**

In my case it was caused by missing getters/setters on fields of response class. There is a constructor, which was used by GSON, but not jersey/jackson. But the annoying thing is, this tools just returned null and not thrown any exception. So still, the question is, how to debug such errors, is it possible to force jersey/jackson to print the problems they find, and not such childisch behaviour ;)

Comment: Which tool returned null? What does constructor have to do with serializing JSON (they are only used for deserializing, i.e. when reading JSON, creating Objects)?

Comment: But there is, in general, nothing wrong in returning null from data-binding; or write JSON with value 'null'. What exactly should be thrown and why? Do you have code examples? What is the actual concrete problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dealt with the problem by using [gson](/questions/tagged/gson) to serialize manually objects to JSON, and I declared the function returned type to `String`, and I hadn't any problems with deploying and using it under [weblogic](/questions/tagged/weblogic) and with debugging errors, so this is my works-for-me solution that I would recommend to anyone having similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the `toString` method of the object being returned?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm writing into logs. And the object is correct and complete.

Comment: It was no the problem, but problem with the code still. I still expect the tool to print the error instead of just null returning.

Comment: Can you add unit tests for the serialization/deserialization of your objects with Jackson?

Comment: @lechlukasz What exactly would be error? Null is a perfectly acceptable JSON value to serialize, in general case.

Comment: The error was the value was not serialized, but this error was nowhere displayed.